# Segfault trying to strcpy a char *

Tags: gdb, segmentation-fault, strlen, strcpy

I am in a introductory C++ course and my program is segfaulting in my copy function. when I use GDB it says it cant access the char * at location 0x0. the odd thing is that I have written this function many times before without any errors.

```
class question 
{
public:
question();
~question();
int set_question(char * question);
int copy_question(question & to_copy);
int clear_question();
int display(); 
char* retrieve_question();
char* retrieve_answer(); 
private:
char* your_question;
char* correct_answer;

};
```

///////////////////

```
int question::set_question(char * question)
{
your_question = new char [strlen(question)+1];
strcpy(your_question, question);

}
```

this is the error code in GDB

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   [Switching to Thread 1 (LWP 1)]
>   0x00013af8 in question::set_question (this=0x0, question=0x257a8 "do you like movies??")
>       at question.cpp:51
>
> 51          your_question = new char [strlen(question)+1];
>
> (gdb) p strlen(question)
>
> > $1 = 27
>
> (gdb) p your_question
>
> > Cannot access memory at address 0x0

Answer (score 0):

I'm not professional at C++, but before you call member function `set_question`, are you initialized the class `question`? It seems that the `question` class is not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the set_question method on a non-initialized object. You can see this from GDB output:

```
question::set_question (this=0x0, question=0x257a8 "do you like movies??")
```

'this' should not be 0x0

The problem is outside of this method. Basically, the newly allocated array cannot be assigned  to 'your_question' member because the whole 'question' object is non existent.

You are probably not doing exactly the following, but this should illustrate the problem:

```
question *q = NULL;
q->set_question(...);
```